# Dropdown menu in table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to apply twitter bootstrap dropdown to table cell of my table:
http://jsfiddle.net/NzvKC/500/
So this doesn't work. I did it according to [this](http://cameronspear.com/demos/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/).
However it works like this:

```
<li class="dropdown span2" id="chamber">
            <a href="#" class="btn dropdown-toggle sr-only" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Name
            <b class="caret"></b>
            <br><br>
            </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li class="liInner" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Value</a></li>
          </ul>
            </li>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This doesn't work too http://jsfiddle.net/NzvKC/526/ however it works here: http://cameronspear.com/demos/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the hover script. Get the code from the [cameronspear page](http://cameronspear.com/blog/bootstrap-dropdown-on-hover-plugin/) and your example will work.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="http://cameronspear.com/downloads/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js"></script>
```

Comment: Found that my solution of problem isn't best, gonna recreate question.